# Bind and distinguish 2 equals joysticks new input system Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, system, joystick

I am making a Pad Dance Game. I have 2 pad dances, they works like a joystick on Pc, they almost have the same number/button sequence(because they are not from the same company). The problem is when I click one pad and the other has the same gamepad number the action works in both player. I need the input system to distinguish if I am pressing the same number button from joystisck one or two. The image below shows how the input system detect the binding for the up arrow icon on the pad 1("botao1") and 2("botao11"), there is no difference if I am pressing joystick one or two. I tried to create 2 differents Action Map, didn't work, because the biding system don't recognize if am pressing joystick one or two. Any clues? Tks in advance

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Akqxf9L5QqUIhMpO6Xzg1wds6c5MJA?e=OMt16v  Link for the image

Answer (score 0):

You need to duplicate the inputs, one for each pad (so for example "Left_Player1" and "Left_Player2"). You configure both inputs identically, except that they must have different JoyNum values.

Comment: Tks for the answers. Sorry, but where exactly I can define "they must have different JoyNum values"? I duplicated the Input Actions(each player has a different one), i didn't put the same name/function for the buttons, same situation, but i don't figure how to put different joyNum values.  Tks again!  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Akqxf9L5QqUIhMpPjqzPc2e8IL3V9w?e=Mzj28s (another image trying with 2 Input Action Map)

Comment: Your screen capture is showing the Player1 GameObject, not an ActionT1 button.

Comment: I have made a folder with images and one video showing what is happening.  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Akqxf9L5QqUIhMpVs3gq5JVT7ebejw?e=jzrOPU. A also tried to check what pad is being clicked by using "Joystick.All" and "Joystick.current" but without result.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0c7Aav8v0rU&list=PLZtVzpLVEw56J63ZA2CV9tbwiCopj-IPv  A kind of solution

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still has this problem, here is how worked around it:

• Gave my players some negative Controlled ID

• When a button from any controller is pressed all players will receive this input, because yes, I could not figure out a solution for this.

• So before the code triggered by the controller is executed I check if my player controller ID matches the device ID passed within the context passed by the controller when a button is pressed.

```
public void ButtonXPressed(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (controllerID < 0)
            AssignControllerID(context.control.device.deviceId);

        if (context.control.device.deviceId != controllerID)
            return;

        WhateverXIsSupposedToDoFunction();
    }
```

Now, since all players will receive this command, all players will have the same ID. So before assigning the ID you should check if the ID being assigned already matches the ID of another player.

In my case, my game has always only 2 players. If the number of players for your game changes, or can increase too much, you might have to get a bit creative with how you perform these checks.

```
void AssignController(int deviceID)
    {
        if (P1)
        {
            if (controllerID < 0) 
                controllerID = deviceID;
            return;
        }
//If P2
        int p1id = GameObject.Find("GameController1").GetComponent<GameController>().controllerID;
        if (p1id < 0 || p1id == deviceID)
            return;

        if (controllerID < 0)
            controllerID = deviceID;
    }
```

Finally. It is important to reset the ID back to a negative value when the controller disconnects.

It worked fine for me, hopefully it helps anyone else who comes across this.